# Simple embedded VLC plugin on HTML page, starting at a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, vlc

I am a novice at this. I am embedding a vlc plugin in an HTML page and can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to jump to a certain time. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Viewer</title>
<body onload=>
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       mute="true"
       autoplay="yes"
       loop="no"
       width="640"
       height="480"
       src=video
       id="vlc"
       name="vlc" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
vlc.input.time = 90000;
//-->

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE
I am now using the object tag instead of the embed tag. I am able to access the vlc object, but every time I do, the video disappears, but not the audio. Any thoughts? video is just a marker for any mpg file. Here is my new code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Viewer</title>
<body>
<center>
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc" height="500" width="600">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
    <param name="Src" value=video />
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
vlc.input.time = 90000;
//-->
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```